# How to solve [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am doing a login function in Flutter. I want to use the error message shown at the alert message. Now I am getting this error:

```
E/flutter ( 2690): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 2690): User does not exist
E/flutter ( 2690): ^
```

Here is my code:

```
Future login(String url, {Map body}) async {
    return http.post(url, body: body).then((http.Response response) {
        print(response.body);

        if(json.decode(response.body) == "User does not exist") {
            print("wrong email");
        }
    });
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `User does not exist` is not valid JSON. This is what the error message is telling you.

To be valid JSON, it would have to contain quotes.

There are two options:

1. Change the server to encode the response as JSON.
2. Do not try to decode the response as JSON.

   Simply use:

   ```
   if(response.body == "User does not exist")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try using this :

```
Future login(String url, {Map body}) async {
  var response = await http.post(url, body: body)

  if(json.decode(response.body) == "User does not exist") {
    print("wrong email");
   // return something here :)
  } else{
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. It still has error == >> Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Comment: I try already, put if(response.body == "User does not exist") can work, thank you very much